# Search a table in all databases in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

In Hive, how do we search a table by name in all databases?

I am a Teradata user. Is there any counterpart of systems tables (present in Teradata) like dbc.tables, dbc.columns which are present in HIVE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should query the metastore.

You can find the connection properties within `hive-site.xml`

**bash**

```
<$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml grep -A1 jdo
```

---

```
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
--
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
--
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
--
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>cloudera</value>
```

Within the metastore you can use a query similar to the following

**mysql**

```
select          *

from                            metastore.DBS             as d

                join            metastore.TBLS            as t 

                on              t.DB_ID =
                                d.DB_ID  

where           t.TBL_NAME  like '% ... put somthing here ... %'

order by       d.NAME 
              ,t.TBL_NAME                                          
;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use SQL like to search a table.
Example:
I want to search a table with the name starting from "Benchmark" I don't know the rest of it.

**Input in HIVE CLI:**

```
show tables like 'ben*'
```

**Output:**

```
+-----------------------+--+
|       tab_name        |
+-----------------------+--+
| benchmark_core_month  |
| benchmark_core_qtr    |
| benchmark_core_year   |
+-----------------------+--+
3 rows selected (0.224 seconds)
```

---

Or you can try below command if you are using Beeline

```
!tables
```

Note: It will work with Beeline only (JDBC client based)

More about beeline: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/02/migrating-from-hive-cli-to-beeline-a-primer/

Comment: Unfortunately, this query searches only in default database or database selected with `use`.

Answer (score 5):

you can also use hdfs to find a table in all databases:

the path of hive databases is:

```
/apps/hive/warehouse/
```

so, by using hdfs :

```
hdfs dfs -find /apps/hive/warehouse/ -name t*
```

Comment: How to check the path of hive database in my system? I don't see such a path you have mentioned above

Comment: This path is not in the OS file system but is in the HDFS file system, you should run hdfs dfs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/, you should also check the access permission if you are able to read this path

Answer (score 3):

Searching for tables with name containing *infob* across all Hive databases

```
for i in `hive -e "show schemas"`; do echo "Hive DB: $i"; hive -e "use $i; show tables"|grep "infob"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Hive stores all its metadata information in Metastore. Metastore schema can be found at: link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12471108/HiveMetaStore.pdf

It has tables like DBS for database, TBLS for tables and Columns. You may use appropriate join, to find out table name or column names.

Answer (score 2):

That's an extention of Mantej Singh's answer: you can use pyspark to find tables across all Hive databases (not just one):

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark import SparkContext, HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

dbnames = [row.databaseName for row in sqlContext.sql('SHOW DATABASES').collect()]

tnames = []
for dbname in dbnames:
    tnames.append(sqlContext.sql('SHOW TABLES IN {} LIKE "%your_pattern%"'.format(dbname)))

tables = reduce(DataFrame.union, tnames)
tables.show()
```

The way to do this is to iterate through the databases searching for table with a specified name.

Answer (score 1):

@hisi's answer is elegant. However it induce an error with lacking memory for GC on our cluster. So, there is another less elegant approach that works for me.

Let `foo` is the table name to search. So

```
hadoop fs -ls -R -C /apps/hive/warehouse/ 2>/dev/null | grep '/apps/hive/warehouse/[^/]\{1,\}/foo$'
```

If one does not remember exact name of table but only substring `bar` in table name, then command is

```
hadoop fs -ls -R -C /apps/hive/warehouse/ 2>/dev/null | grep '/apps/hive/warehouse/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}$' | grep bar
```